# error when running map reduce in CouchBase Lite

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-view

I am trying to use map-reduce on CouchBase Lite. I have documents and they are being channelised. All doucments what I want are coming to Couchbase Lite. But When I Try to run map-reduce on them I am getting the following error

`com.couchbase.lite.CouchbaseLiteException: Error when calling map block of view 'calendar', Status: 593 (HTTP 500 Application callback block failed)`

Below is my map reduce function

`private View createView(Database database){
        View calendarView = database.getView("calendar");
        calendarView.setMap(new Mapper() {
            @Override
            public void map(Map<String, Object> document, Emitter emitter) {
                emitter.emit((long) document.get("date"),(long) document.get("cost"));
            }
        },"2");
        return calendarView;
    }`

and Below is the part of main where I am calling the view and querying over it

`View calendarView = createView(database);
        Query query = database.getView("calendar").createQuery();
        query.setStartKey(1472467249448l);
        query.setEndKey(1472553649449l);
        QueryEnumerator result = null;
        try {
            result = query.run();
        } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (Iterator<QueryRow> it = result; it.hasNext(); ) {
            QueryRow row = it.next();
            Log.d(TAG, row.getValue().toString());
        }`

Comment: This means an exception is being thrown inside your map function.  Perhaps there is an invalid cast going on?  I know this is Java (right?) but in my experience with C# you cannot cast directly from object to long if the actual value is int, ulong, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As borrrden said in a comment above, `Application callback block failed` means your map function threw an exception. Use a debugger to find out what it is.

A likely possibility is that one of the documents in your database does not have a `date` property. In that case your map function would be passing `null` to the first (`key`) parameter of `emit`, which is an invalid argument.